# android bottom sheet with curved top edges

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, bottom-sheet

I have a bottomsheet that has constraint layout as root.How to curve the top edges?
Tried this code but it's not working.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_bg"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">
```

**bottom_sheet_bg** is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="@dimen/dimen_20dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something to keep in mind is that view structures that an application programmer creates are usually placed into some type of view group enclosure by Android. Let's take a simple app and color the background of the main activity a blue and color the background with the curved top red. This is to better show what is going on.

Here is an image from the layout inspector of Android Studio:

[image]

As you can see, the curved top of the background drawable is there but the corners have a white background which is the background of the *FrameLayout design_bottom_sheet*. This is also true in your app but the background colors of your background and of the *FrameLayout* are both white, so it appears that the rounded corners are just not there. They are present but are masked by the white of the background of the *FrameLayout*.

To solve this you can search for the *design_bottom_sheet* and explicitly change its background to transparent, but it may be better to approach this issue through styles.

In your styles file create the following:

```
<style name="BottomSheetDialogStyle" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheetModalStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="BottomSheetModalStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bottom_sheet_bg</item>
</style>
```

(Your styles may differ, but the concept will still apply.)

In the *BottomSheetDialogFragment* add the following:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.BottomSheetDialogStyle);
}
```

or just add the `setStyle()` line if you already have `onCreate()` defined. This code will prevent the *design_bottom_sheet* from drawing a background.

This will show the following:

[image]

and in the Layout Inspector:

[image]

Change the colors to what you need but keep in mind that the color that shows at the corners will now be whatever color shows under the *FrameLayout*.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the way I achieved it is simply through the drawables.

rounded_dialog.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
        android:topRightRadius="16dp"/>
</shape>
```

inside res/values/styles.xml

```xml
 <style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppModalStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_dialog</item>
    </style>
```

and inside the java/kotlin

```java
final BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(getActivity(), R.style.AppBottomSheetDialogTheme));
```